# How to avoid duplicated words in an array

Tags: ios, swift

I have a question about Swift.

I am making a quiz app to learn English words and I want to display the words in the Word class once the player gets right like the picture attached below. However, as you can see, the list has many duplicated values. How can I fix that? Thank you in advance.[List View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jd57r.png)

```
@Query var playerInfos: [PlayerInfo1]

List {
      ForEach(Array(Set(playerInfos)), id: \.self) { playerInfo in
             ForEach(Array(Set(playerInfo.correctWords)), id: \.self) { index in
                        Text("\(displayeWord[index].word)")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                }
            }
-----------------
@Model
class PlayerInfo1 {
    var playerScore : Int
    var correctWords : [Int] // store the index of the words that the player gets right 
    
    init(playerScore: Int, correctWords: [Int]) {
        self.playerScore = playerScore
        self.correctWords = correctWords
    }
}
-----------------
class Word : Identifiable {
 
}

let displayeWord : [Word] = [
    Word(word: "Arvo", meaning1: "午後", meaning2: "午前"),
    Word(word: "Bin", meaning1: "ゴミ箱", meaning2: "壺"),
    Word(word: "Runners", meaning1: "スニーカー", meaning2: "走る人"),
```

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  
Show just enough code to replicate your issue when we compile and run it.

Comment: This looks more like you have bad data persisted, if you fix that I believe your view code would be pretty straightforward. For instance is it so bad that you have several PlayerInfo1 instances even though they are for the same user?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Hi Thanks for your comment. There are 5 classes from the playerInfo1 to playerInfo5 because the player can choose how many words he wants to try from 10 to 50 and I wanted to display them separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a different approach, using a state variable and `calculating`
the set of unique words to display in the `.onAppear`, instead of multiple `ForEach` loops in the body of the view.

Example code:

EDIT-1

To sort the array of unique words.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // @Query var playerInfos: [PlayerInfo1]
    
    // simulated @Query, for testing
    let playerInfos: [PlayerInfo1] = [
        PlayerInfo1(playerScore: 1, correctWords: [1]),
        PlayerInfo1(playerScore: 2, correctWords: [2]),
        PlayerInfo1(playerScore: 3, correctWords: [3]),
        PlayerInfo1(playerScore: 4, correctWords: [4])
    ]
    
    let displayedWord: [Word] = [
        Word(word: "Arvo", meaning1: "午後", meaning2: "午前"),
        Word(word: "Bin", meaning1: "ゴミ箱", meaning2: "壺"),
        Word(word: "Runners", meaning1: "スニーカー", meaning2: "走る人"),
        Word(word: "Arvo", meaning1: "午後", meaning2: "午前"),
        Word(word: "Bin", meaning1: "ゴミ箱", meaning2: "壺"),
        Word(word: "Runners", meaning1: "スニーカー", meaning2: "走る人")]
    
    @State private var uniqueWords: [Word] = [] 
    
    var body: some View {
        List(uniqueWords) { unique in
            Text("\(unique.word)")
        }
        .onAppear {
            Array(Set(playerInfos)).forEach { playerInfo in
                Array(Set(playerInfo.correctWords)).forEach { index in
                    if index < displayedWord.count {
                        if !uniqueWords.contains(where: {$0 == displayedWord[index]}) {
                            uniqueWords.append(displayedWord[index])
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
           uniqueWords.sort() // <--- here
        }
    }
    
}

struct Word: Identifiable, Equatable, Comparable {  // <--- here
    let id = UUID()
    var word: String
    var meaning1: String
    var meaning2: String
    
    static func == (lhs: Word, rhs: Word) -> Bool {
        lhs.word == rhs.word && lhs.meaning1 == rhs.meaning1 && lhs.meaning2 == rhs.meaning2
    }

    // --- here
    static func < (lhs: Word, rhs: Word) -> Bool {
        lhs.word < rhs.word
    }

}
```

If you have to use a class for `Word`, use:

```
class Word: Identifiable, Equatable, Comparable {
    let id = UUID()
    var word: String
    var meaning1: String
    var meaning2: String
    
    init(word: String, meaning1: String, meaning2: String) {
        self.word = word
        self.meaning1 = meaning1
        self.meaning2 = meaning2
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: Word, rhs: Word) -> Bool {
        lhs.word == rhs.word && lhs.meaning1 == rhs.meaning1 && lhs.meaning2 == rhs.meaning2
    }

    static func < (lhs: Word, rhs: Word) -> Bool {
        lhs.word < rhs.word
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!! 

Can I ask how I can sort the array (uniqueWords) in the order of displayedWord? I want the list to start with Arvo but the order looks random.

Comment: if my answer helped you, consider accepting it by ticking the tick mark next to it. It turns green.

Comment: Updated my answer with the added requirement of sorting the `uniqueWords`.